# Find matches by word and check if it's a link or not

Tags: php

I want to create a PHP array like below, which contains two values, one for the matching word and one to check if the match is a link or not.

**Input**

```
$string = "test <a href=\"test\" title=\"test\">test</a>"
```

What can I do here to find all matches of the word 'test' and check if the founded match is a link or not?

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
           Array 
           (
               [0] test
               [1] false
           )
    [1] => 
           Array 
           (
               [0] test
               [1] true
           )
)
```

Comment: I don't understand: you known in advance the word to search and you want know if is it in 'href' or you want search valid links (like http://....) or what?

Comment: The output shoulld get both *false* and *true* for the same word and input? I don't understand. Can you give a better example?

Comment: I wan't to check if the String contains the word 'test' and then check if the match is surrounded with href tags. When it is a surrounded with these tags than its true otherwise it's false.

Comment: But in your example output you give both true and false for the same thing. It is confusing. Please give a correct example.

Comment: Also, the input in your example has *"test"* occurring 3 times, not counting the first occurrence outside of the tag. Yet your output has only two entries. I can't make sense of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?php

    $string ="test <a href=\"test\" title=\"test\">test</a>";
    $link ='';
    $word = '';
    $flag = true;
     for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){

       if($string[$i] == '<' && $string[$i+1] == 'a'){
         $flag=false;
         while($string[$i++] != '>')
         {

         }
         while($string[$i] != '<' && $string[$i+1] != '/' && $string[$i+2] != 'a' && $string[$i+3] != '>'){
             $link .= $string[$i++];
           }
       }
       else{
        if($flag)
          $word.=$string[$i];
       }
     }
    echo 'Link :'.$link . "<br/>";
    echo 'Word:'.$word;
    // You can now manipulate Link and word as you wish 

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! thats where I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression for this:

```
$string = 'test <a href="http://test" title="mytitle">link text</a>';

if (preg_match("#^\s*(.*?)\s*<a\s.*?href\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"].*?>(.*?)</a\s*>#si",
         $string, $match)) {
    $textBefore = $match[1]; // test
    $href       = $match[2]; // http://test     
    $anchorText = $match[3]; // link text
    // deal with these elements as you wish...
}
```

This solution is not case-sensitive, it will work with `<A ...>...</A>` just as well. If the *href* value is delimited with single quotes instead of double quotes, it will still work. Surrounding spaces of each value are ignored (trimmed).